# passing self data into a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, self

I'm trying to set a function to do something like this

```
   def __binaryTreeInsert(self, toInsert, currentNode=getRoot(), parentNode=None):
```

where current node starts as root, and then we change it to a different node in the method and recursivly call it again.

However, i cannot get the 'currentNode=getRoot()' to work. If i try calling the funcion getRoot() (as above) it says im not giving it all the required variables, but if i try to call self.getRoot() it complains that self is an undefined variable. Is there a way i can do this without having to specify the root while calling this method?

EDIT: The base case of this method is already

```
if currentNode == None:
```

so using that to set the root wouldn't work

Comment: It seems very strange to me that `getRoot` is evidently a module-level function taking no arguments? Are you using the module global namespace when you want a class instance, or did you forget the `self`, or am I missing something?

Comment: `is None` is generally preferred to `== None`.

Comment: `__foo` methods should generally be avoided. They don't actually make anything private (this is impossible in Python), but they can make subclassing and testing harder.

Comment: If this is a binary tree class, I would expect a method to be named something like `_insert` (or even `__setitem__`), not `__binaryTreeInsert`.

Comment: @mike, this is a red black tree. The method the user calles is .insert(item), which then calls __binaryTreeInsert to get the item into the tree, and then __redBlackInsert to rebalance the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `arg=None` is the idiomatic Python sentinel value for an non-supplied argument, it doesn't *have* to be `None`.  In Lua, for instance, the idiomatic non-supplied argument is an empty table.  We can actually apply that to this case:

```
class Foo:
    sentinel = {}
    def bar(self, arg=sentinel):
        if arg is self.sentinel:
            print "You didn't supply an argument!"
        else:
            print "The argument was", arg

f = Foo()
f.bar(123)
f.bar()
f.bar(None)
f.bar({})
```

Output:

```
The argument was 123
You didn't supply an argument!
The argument was None
The argument was {}
```

This works for any case except explicitly passing `Foo.sentinel`, because `Foo.sentinel` is guaranteed to have a unique address -- meaning, `x is Foo.sentinel` is *only* true when x *is* `Foo.sentinel` :)  Thus, due to the closure we've created around `Foo.sentinel`, there is only one object that can create an ambiguous situation, and it will never be used by accident.

Comment: What i was looking for. I partially want to do this for further abstraction, but mostly i was just curious if/how it could be done.

Comment: Always inherit `object` rather than nothing so that you are using new-style classes.

Comment: @Mike the class that this method is hosted in inherits from object

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
def __binaryTreeInsert(self, toInsert, currentNode=None, parentNode=None):
   if currentNode is None:
      currentNode = self.getRoot()

...
```

Comment: I thought of that, but the problem is the base case of the recursion is 

'if curentNode is None:'

so it wouldn't work with the rest of the method

Comment: @user, You are going to give more info then. If you look at this you can still check afterwards if it is `None` or not.

Comment: `None` is just a sentinel value here, you can use an arbitrary object instead of it if the `currentNode is None` case does already have a meaning … you can use, for example, `False` or `True`.

Comment: @voyager, i am adding an item to a binary tree as part of building a red black tree. What this method is going to do is go to the left or right child of the current node every recursion (depending on the data), and if that same left or right child node is none, then that is where this new node is going to be added. 

The reason doing 2 checks wouldn't work is that if there was ever an empty node, it would set it back to root first, and never add the child node

Comment: @Alexander, smart thinking, thanks :). Coming from a java background i keep forgetting that variables aren't strong typed.

Comment: @user272689, Python is strongly typed; objects have a strong type. Python variables do not have types, strong or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

When a function or method is defined, the `def` line is evaluated immediately, including any keyword arguments. For this reason, things like function calls and mutable objects are usually not appropriate for default arguments.

The solution is instead to use a sentinel value. `None` is most common, but for the cases that `None` would be a valid value, you can use another sentinel, for example:

```
not_provided = object()
def _binaryTreeInsert(self, toInsert, currentNode=not_provided, parentNode=None):
    if currentNode is not_provided:
        currentNode = self.getRoot()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def __binaryTreeInsert(self, toInsert, currentNode=0, parentNode=None):
    if not currentNode: 
        currentNode = self.getRoot()
```